# Can you identify a user from the access_token?

Tags: support, api-v2, authentication, documentation

I have the `access_token` after authentication from the user. At this point I don't know with which sites this user has registered. Is it possible to get user information like the display name or profile picture from here?

I'm aware of [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me)  , but this requires a `site` to be specified. I suppose I can find the users associated sites with [/me/associated](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) and use that info, but... is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`/me/associated` route<sup>Doc</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) *is* the preferred way to turn an `access_token` into a list of users, it returns the collection of per-site user details that can be quickly fetched.  It's basically the user's [account tab](http://stackexchange.com/users/27899/aldrin?tab=accounts).

If you need more details about a user on a give site, then turn around and hit `/me` (or `/users/{ids}`) on the sites you've discovered via `/me/associated`.

As for display names and profile images, you will have to make at least one call to a site specific method; I typically advise consumers to only query the user's top account (by rep) for that information, it's the same on all sites for > 90% of users with multiple accounts (and > 50% of users only have accounts on a single site).  However, if you intend to display all of a user's accounts you will have to make multiple requests.