# Provide a way to get display name via access token

Tags: feature-request, api, users, authentication

Please include a new (network) method with the ability to gather display name and profile image directly via access token.

Right now to retrieve this information you have to first authenticate a user, second get their associated accounts and third call [users/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me).

However the problem is, that if a user, for whatever reason, has no associated accounts, there is no chance to get their name and/or image.

Comment: Related:  [Can you identify a user from the access_token?](http://stackapps.com/questions/3985/can-you-identify-a-user-from-the-access-token)

Comment: Nearly duplicate:  [/associated should include user's display name and the api_site_parameter](http://stackapps.com/questions/4755/associated-should-include-users-display-name-and-the-api-site-parameter)